# Meteor can not use $elementMatch

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I use `$elementMatch` to query on user collection:

```
Template.AccountInfo.helpers({
  counter() {
    return Meteor.users.find({
      accounts: {
        $elementMatch: {
          bal: {
            $exists: false
          }
        }
      }
    }).fetch();
  },
});
```

This query works fine on server, but on client I only get below error. What could be wrong?

```
Exception in template helper: Error: Unrecognized operator: $elementMatch ...
```

Comment: As MasterM write bellow, maybe you have a typo in the code: $elemMatch instead of $elementMatch. The mongodb documentation notice that If you specify only a single <query> condition in the $elemMatch expression, you do not need to use $elemMatch.

Answer (score 2):

On the client, Meteor uses [MiniMongo](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/minimongo), which implements a subset of the MongoDB operators.

Are you sure that you did not mean [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/), which was implemented in [MiniMongo in v0.7.2](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v072-2014-03-18)? I am wondering how this is working on the server.

Anyway, since you only have a single criterion, you don't really need it as it is.

Some of the operators are not implemented, and I cannot find any reference to any called `$elementMatch`.

Those incompatibilities are documented in the [Notes](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/minimongo/NOTES) file. There are limitations to what `$elemMatch` can do on the client, but it does not seem to apply to your case.

> Unsupported selectors:
>
> - $elemMatch inside $all
> - geoqueries other than $near ($nearSphere, $geoIntersects, $geoWithin)